# How to have modules gain access to tkinter widgets from another module

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I'm just new to all these module stuff in python. I had this sort of Cafe Management System whom I've been separating the gui and functions into modules. Currently, I have no idea how to have the function modules have access to the tkinter widgets in the gui module. Here's the example.

This is a text widget from the gui module:

`rcpt = Text(rcptmain, width=50, height=30, bd=4) rcpt.grid(row=1, column=0)`

This code from one of the function modules would load a text file to the text widget:

```
filename = open(filename, 'r')
whatev = filename.read()
rcpt.delete("1.0", END)
rcpt.insert(END, whatev)
filename.close()`
```

Comment: It's very unclear what the code for GUI is and what is the code that you want to access GUI elements from.

Comment: I mean I wanted `rcpt = Text()` from the gui module to be accessed in the other module.

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this.

gui module.

```
rcpt = Text(rcptmain, width=50, height=30, bd=4) rcpt.grid(row=1, column=0)

def display_data(data):
    rcpt.delete(0, END)
    rcpt.insert(0, data + '\n')
    return data
```

Then second module

```
import gui

filename = open(filename, 'r')
whatev = filename.read()
gui.display_data(whatev)
filename.close()
```